# Perl: Decimal to 32bits hex convert

Tags: perl, hex, decimal

I want to convert decimal number `64` into hex representation: `0x00000040`. I am using

```
printf("0x%X", 64);
```

but it gives output: `0x40`. Can anyone please help me how to represent the decimal number in `0x00000000` format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the length of the field between the `%` and the `X` (e.g. `%8X`). By default, the number will be padded with spaces, but using a leading zero for the length (e.g. `%08X`) will cause `printf` to pad with zeroes instead. Therefore, the following can be used:

```
printf("0x%08X", 64);
```

Comment: Good job on finding a solution and writing your own answer! :)